# How to format timestamp in Javascript to show the correct time in the relevant timezone

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, datetime-format

I have an issue with handling time in JavaScript. I have a timestamp in a document in firebase and I have a cloud function which is supposed to send out a notification. I would like to send out the notification with the timestamp properly formatted as the current time zone in the UK (which currently is BST or UTC+1 or GMT+1). Below is the code I have ...

```
exports.sendNotificationNewRota = functions.firestore
  .document('rota/{attendanceId}')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {
    const transaction = snapshot.data();

    var dateIn = transaction.timeIn.toDate();

    let timeIn = dateIn.toLocaleTimeString( {
      timezone: 'Europe/London',
      timeZoneName: 'long',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute:'2-digit'});

    console.log(timeIn);
```

The output of this code gives me a time in UTC. This may be fine when BST will finish but not now. Is there way to handle time properly?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is *explicitly* requesting a particular time zone. If you don't do that, you'll get the time formatted for the actual time zone of the client.

Comment: if I remove timezone: 'Europe/London', it still gives me a UTC time...

Comment: When I type `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` in my browser, I get the time in my correct local time zone (US "Central" daylight time).

Comment: You're not calling toLocaleTimeString correctly.  Use the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg I lost so much time on this one but eventually I realized it was a typo in my code. Anyone having the same problem make sure to use `timeZone` instead of `timezone`

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to function signature of `Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()`

```
dateObj.toLocaleTimeString([locales[, options]])
```

Details are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

You effectively pass your configurations to the `locales` parameter, for your code to work you need to add an empty first parameter. Alternatively, you can also specify it as `'en-UK'` for example:

```js
exports.sendNotificationNewRota = functions.firestore
  .document('rota/{attendanceId}')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {
    const transaction = snapshot.data();

    var dateIn = transaction.timeIn.toDate();

    let timeIn = dateIn.toLocaleTimeString([],{ //<-- fix here
      timezone: 'Europe/London',
      timeZoneName: 'long',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute:'2-digit'});

    console.log(timeIn);
```

Comment: I have tried with [], with 'en-UK' and also with 'en-GB' but I am still getting UTC time. This is what I get in the conole: 11:00 AM Coordinated Universal Time. I would like 12PM British Summer Time. I am thinkning that maybe the problem is the fact that this code run in a cloud function... If I run in my browser it works fine...